# India Visa after marriage

Tags: visas, passports, india

I am traveling in a month or so to India with my wife. She has a valid passport and valid visa in her maiden name. The only document we have updated after marriage is her social security card. I was told by two Indian consulates that she can travel with her current passport (which has her maiden name) as long as her passport name matches her visa name matches her air ticket name. Is this true? Or will the updated social security information cause some problems?

Comment: Why do you disbelieve what the consulates told you?

Comment: @MichaelHampton although the consulates gave me the same end answer, they had different reasoning. Considering I have multiple thousands of dollars on the line, and I don't want to get stuck on the other side of the world, I thought I'd do a little double checking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only documents you need while traveling are the following.

- Passport
- Visa
- Flight Ticket
- Proof of accommodation

If the name matches in all those, you won't have any problem. Social Security card is not checked while traveling. This applies to all international travel.